# Fill a rectangle with an image using Mono Cairo Library

Tags: c#, cairo

I am trying to fill an image inside a rectangle. I was able to set the image position correctly to the leftmost corner of the rectangle. However the scaling does not work as expected. Any help on this is appreciated. Below is my code. This is a 1290*1990 dimensions image.

```
        Cairo.Rectangle imageRectangle = new Cairo.Rectangle(50, 100, width, height);

        ctx.NewPath();
        Cairo.ImageSurface imgSurface = new Cairo.ImageSurface("C:/Temp/Image.png");
        ctx.SetSource(imgSurface, topLeftPoint); //topLeft is (50,100)

        float xScale = (float)imageRectangle.Width / (float)imgSurface.Width;
        float yScale = (float)imageRectangle.Height / (float)imgSurface.Height;

        //Reposition the image to the rectangle origin
        ctx.Translate(imageRectangle.X, imageRectangle.Y);
        ctx.Scale(xScale, yScale);

        ctx.Paint();
```

Thanks!!

Comment: what are the values of `xScale` and `yScale`?

Comment: It is calculated dynamically. In one of the test case, these are the values, imageRectangle.Width=387.7299,  imageRectangle.Height=596.663147, So xScale= 0.299868435 and yScale=0.299830735

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution. I was setting the source at the wrong place. Below is the right code

```
    Cairo.Rectangle imageRectangle = new Cairo.Rectangle(50, 100, width, height);

    ctx.NewPath();
    Cairo.ImageSurface imgSurface = new Cairo.ImageSurface("C:/Temp/Image.png");


    float xScale = (float)imageRectangle.Width / (float)imgSurface.Width;
    float yScale = (float)imageRectangle.Height / (float)imgSurface.Height;

    //Reposition the image to the rectangle origin
    ctx.Translate(imageRectangle.X, imageRectangle.Y);
    ctx.Scale(xScale, yScale);

    ctx.SetSource(imgSurface); 
    ctx.Paint();
```

Thanks!